# Delete 10 % of old Object in MongoDB collection

Tags: java, mongodb, collections

I want to delete 10 % of Objects for example.

I get the collection and sort it by time. Now I have an iterator. I want to say remove, but it doesn't work. Clear doesn't work. How can I delete only the first Objects?

Try1

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().sort(new BasicDBObject("utc-stamp", 1)).iterator();
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            Document document = (Document) cursor.next();
            document.clear();

        }
```

Try 2

```
MongoCursor<Document> iterator = collection.find().sort(new BasicDBObject("utc-stamp", 1)).iterator();
for(int i = 0; i< collection.count()-2; i++) {
    iterator.next().clear();
}
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    docs.add(iterator.next());
}
```

I have no Idea. I can get the name of collection and the size of objects.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: What's the purpose. Are you looking to maintain a collection that only has room for a limited number of records. i.e. delete older records to create room for new records if your collection is full.  If this is what you're looking for, use a `CappedCollection`. Refer to this : https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/

Answer (score 0):

```
collection.deleteOne(document);
```

You have to call the delete operation on the collection to remove the document from the collection. Refer the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/remove/).

Note: If 100 documents are to be deleted, 100 separate DB delete call are made. Also, please consider @Siddharth Ajmera's suggestion to use capped collections.